# How to enable ajax update in yii2 GridView?

Tags: ajax, gridview, yii2

How to enable ajax update in yii2 GridView ?

Ex: GridView GET Method

```
`http://localhost/borderland/web/item/index?ItemSearch[code]=&ItemSearch[name]=&ItemSearch[price]=&ItemSearch[availability]=&ItemSearch[itemCategory_id]=2&sort=price
```

`
I need to use ajax update instead of using GET method. How to enable that in Yii2 GridView  ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `PJax` widget like below:

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
// ... configuration here
]);
?>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

It is suggested to take a look at the `Yii2`'s official wiki: [**Yii 2.0: How to use GridView with AJAX**](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/655/how-to-use-gridview-with-ajax/)

---

**If URL changes with `Ajax` requests using `PJax`:**

As `Yii2`'s official document says:

> Pjax only deals with the content enclosed between its begin() and end() calls, called the body content of the widget. By default, any link click or form submission (for those forms with data-pjax attribute) within the body content will trigger an AJAX request. In responding to the AJAX request, Pjax will send the updated body content (based on the AJAX request) to the client which will replace the old content with the new one. **The browser's URL will then be updated using pushState**. The whole process requires no reloading of the layout or resources (js, css).

You can disable `pushState` (Updating the `URL` with `Ajax` request) like below:

```
enablePushState => FALSE
```

I mean:

```
\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(
    [
        'enablePushState'=>FALSE
    ]
);
```

---

**How to make action buttons working with `PJax`**

As `Yii2`'s official Wiki says:

> if you check closely the rendered `HTML`, you will see that the links do have the `HTML5` attribute `data-pjax="0"`. That means that if you don't wish `PJax` to handle your links, you need to add this `HTML5` attribute to them.

---

**How to Update my GridView**

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#idofyourpjaxwidget'});
```

Comment: Thanks!!. I did that. Then Ajax and GET URL both working together. Ajax call success and URL also changing. How to fix that?